# Do Pigments, Dyes (with plastics) or Plastic Itself Exist that Appear White but are NIR transparent?

Tags: plastics

I am looking to make a NIR (Near Infrared) window for a project I am working on but need it to appear white rather than the typical Reddish Black NIR window found on most remotes.   Does a dye or pigment exist that makes PMMA or PC (open to other injection moldable thermoplastics!) look white but allows NIR (specifically 940nm) to pass with low loss?

Comment: What about the plastics used to encapsulate LED NIR emitters? These are usually, I think, epoxy resins. In fact, these days many IR-based remote controls will use a naked LED with no other window so do you really need an extra window?

Comment: interesting.  Most I have seen are either a blackish appearance or clear.  I will look around for white and report back my findings.